# Convert csv data to specific format DYNAMIC

Tags: arrays, perl, dynamic

I have this front end CSS data stored in a web page. Here is the data in text file.

```
secid,Initial_shares
002826,3777
0028262,3777
0028262,3777
0028262,3777
0028262,3777
0028262,3777
```

I need to convert this text file into the below format. once, i convert it to below format, i will be able to display it on the front end. this format below is used to display data in jqgrid.

```
var secid =
            [
             "002826", "0028262", "0028262", "0028262", "0028262", "0028262"];
var Initial_shares =
        [
            "3777", "3777", "3777", "3777", "3777", "3777"1
        ];
```

In order to convert the text to above format, i have used the below perl code. Please note. This conversion is static. i.e. it knows how many columns are there. In this case, there will be 2 columns. secid and Initial_shares. so here is the static code

```
my @a=();
my @b=();

my @a1=();
my @b1=();

my @perl_array=();
my @filena = split(/\|/, $filename);

open (TXT, "<$filename") || die "Can't open $filename: $!\n";
while (my $line=<TXT>) {
    chomp($line);
    ($a2, $b2) = split /,/, $line;

    push @a,('"', "$a2", '"', ',');
    push @b,('"', "$b2", '"', ',');
}

splice @a,0,4; # this splice is used to remove the header name.
splice @b,0,4; # i.e. first row data- secid, Initial_shares

push @a1,"var secid=[@a]";
push @b1,"var Initial_shares=[@b]";

push @perl_array, "@a1; @b1";
close TXT;
```

The @perl_array will be then exactly similar to the kind of data we were expecting at the start. i wil transfer this perl variable to front end for displaying then.

I need help in the following case. What if instead of 2 columns, there are 5 columns. How can we convert the same csv file to the format mentioned earlier. it should be all dynamic. Can someone shed some light please.

Comment: You need to attempt to come up with the solution yourself, and then we can make appropriate suggestions and corrections as needed.

Comment: @MattJacob- Agreed, but i was hoping to get some help on how to approach it. The main issue is creating the arrays. As you can see, i have to create arrays for each column. if i have 2 columns, i hav to create arrays like a, b & a1,b1 and then use push. Dynamically creating arrays is a problem. Plus how could i dynamically push the data to the dyynamic arrays.

Comment: You might be better served by an array of hash references. Use the first row of your CSV file as the hash keys. The [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module can do this for you very easily. Additionally, it looks like your output is JavaScript arrays, so I would recommend the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module to avoid encoding headaches.

Comment: @MattJacob- Thanks for the approach. i will have a look into these and update accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would have done it, using the suggestions I gave you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Text::CSV;

my $filename = '/path/to/file.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 }) or die Text::CSV->error_diag;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;

$csv->column_names($csv->getline($fh));
my $data = $csv->getline_hr_all($fh);

close($fh);

for my $column ($csv->column_names) {
    my $json = encode_json([ map { $_->{$column} } @$data ]);
    print "var $column = $json;\n";
}
```

Comment: Thats really succinct and clean. Very nice.

Comment: @Matt Jacob- thanks so much. chris Doyle's approach was to help me out on the same code and its really commendable to come up with a solution like tat. Matt had the other approach. i get to learn and understand both the approaches. so thank you guys for this.

Comment: @all- this answer is also right. it gave me the same result as provided by Chris doyle.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to process the header line on its on first, then base don that you can create a hash of arrays which map to each header field. below is a sample code to demonstrate.

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my %dynamic;
    my @fields = split(/,/,<DATA>);
    chomp(@fields);

    while(<DATA>){
      chomp();
      my @data_fields=split(/,/);
      for (my $i=0; $i<@fields; $i++){
        push(@{$dynamic{$fields[$i]}}, '"' . $data_fields[$i] . '"');
      }
    }

    my @data_array;
    foreach (@fields){
      push(@data_array, "var $_ = [" . join(',',@{$dynamic{$_}}) . "];");
    }

    print join("\n",@data_array), "\n";

    __DATA__
    secid,Initial_shares,columna,someothercolumn
    002826,3777,1,2
    0028262,3777,a,b
    0028262,3777,5,6
    0028262,3777,g,h
    0028262,3777,4,5
    0028262,3777,h,j
```

I have printed out the data structure of the final array to show its contents.

```
var secid = ["002826","0028262","0028262","0028262","0028262","0028262"];
var Initial_shares = ["3777","3777","3777","3777","3777","3777"];
var columna = ["1","a","5","g","4","h"];
var someothercolumn = ["2","b","6","h","5","j"];
```

this will dynamically expand or shrink based on your csv input.

Comment: Are you serious ? i would have taken ages to figure this thing out. i literally had tears in my eyes.. you dont know how much it means to me at this moment. thanks again.

Comment: You should test it in your own environment to make sure it works as you expect it to. please let me know how it works out.

Comment: Dyle- this code fits in my already present code nicely. thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear its working for you. If  your question has been answered, dont forget to mark it as answered by selecting the tick next to the answer that best suited you.

Comment: Chris Doyle- i didnt know that. i wil do it now

Comment: It helps the community to know when things have been answered and accepted by the OP

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very simply by reading the file into an array and reformatting it on output

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;
while ( <> ) {
    my @row = /[^,\s]+/g;
    push @{ $data[$_] }, $row[$_] for 0 .. $#row;
}

for my $i ( 0 .. $#data ) {
    my $column = $data[$i];
    printf "var %s = [\n", shift @$column;
    printf "    %s\n", join ', ', map qq{"$_"}, @$column;
    print  "];\n";
}
```

#### output

```
var secid = [
    "002826", "0028262", "0028262", "0028262", "0028262", "0028262"
];
var Initial_shares = [
    "3777", "3777", "3777", "3777", "3777", "3777"
];
```

Comment: As long as your values never have spaces or commas in them... ;-)