# Accessing element of an perl Array element

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a perl code which read `csv` file. It contains `grid` data which needs to be updated at the front end.

First, here is the perl code which reads data and formats it so that the data can be pushed to front end for display.

```
my @array;
for my $column ($csv->column_headers) {
    my $json = encode_json([ map { $_->{$column} } @$data ]);
    push(@array, "$json;");
}
```

The final data is the `@array` which is passed to front end `javascript` code. The contents of `@array` is as follows.

```
["1","2"]; ["dd","ddd"]; ["wow","cool"]; ["HOLD","HOLD"];
```

This data is actually `4` columns with column header names as `Id`, `Name`, `Comment` and `type`. All these data are bundled up together in `@array` and passed to `Javascript`.

```
var header=[];
header[0] = @array[0];
}
```

This code above displays the below output if I do a `console.log(header[0])`; It means it is displaying the first element of the array. but I want to display the first element's element.

```
["1", "2"]
```

whereas it should display below output.

```
["1"]
```

In short, I want to know how can I access array elements elements. I tried using below code but it didn't work. Can someone please suggest?

```
var header=[];
    header[0] = @array[0][0];
```

I am ultimately trying to put this data in grid by using below code.

```
for (var i=0;i<row_cnt;i++){
    var row={};
    row["Id"]=Id[i];
    row["Name"]=Name[i];
    row["Comment"]=Comment[i];
    row["type"]= type[i];
    data[i]=row;                           
}
```

where `Id[i]` will corresponding to `"1"` in first loop and `"2"` in second loop. Similarly it will generate data for other columns. These are then assigned to rows and updated in grid.

As per matts suggestion, I edited the code like this

```
my $json = encode_json($data);
 for my $column ($csv->column_names) {
 push(@data_array, "var $column= $json;");
}
```

Now it displays below values at every cell of the `grid`.

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: If I remember correctly from your previous posts, wasn't your data _already_ in tabular (CSV) format? Whatever you've got here is a strange way to represent tabular data, and I would suggest re-thinking your data structure. What are you ultimately trying to do here?

Comment: @MattJacob- yea, i think the structure is weird. :( i have updated my question with what i ultimately want to achieve.

Comment: I _think_ what you want is an array of objects. I would build that up in Perl first and then encode the entire thing as JSON. Actually, `getline_hr_all` (from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191842/convert-csv-data-to-specific-format-dynamic)) gets you 99% of the way there. Call `encode_json` on the return value, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @MattJacob- i tried this point because i knew i was getting closer. i tried the encode_json function on the overall value. i.e.  my $json = encode_json([ map { $_->{$column} } @$data ]); After this statement, i again wrote encode_json but it didnt work. maybe i didnt code it properly. can you please post the answer here.

Comment: Get rid of the loop, `map`, and array reference, and just encode `$data` by itself.

Comment: @MattJacob- it gives [object Object] at every cell now. edited the code like you suggested. please check the edited post at the end.

Comment: You say you edited your post according to my suggestion, but that wasn't my suggestion. I even posted an answer showing the entirety of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191842/convert-csv-data-to-specific-format-dynamic), I think you just need to swap out the loop at the end for this:

```
my $json = encode_json($data);
print "var data = $json;\n";
```